# How to make Assumptions in IntegrateChangeVariables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

There is a new useful command `IntegrateChangeVariables` since 13.1.
The command has the `Assumptions` option which is very poorly described
in the documentation "Restrictions on the domains of the variables and
parameters in the integral can be specified using Assumptions". I don't
understand the only example to it at the end of
[the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html?q=IntegrateChangeVariables).

Here is my unsuccessful trial to apply that option which leads to an incorret result.

The command in 13.3.1 on Windows 10

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][(-2*Cos[x] + 2 a)/(1 - 2 a*Cos[x] + a^2) /. 
a -> 1/2, {x, 0, \[Pi]}], t, t == Tan[x/2]]
```

returns the input. Because of this reason I try

```
int = IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][(-2*Cos[x] + 2 a)/(1 - 2 a*Cos[x] + a^2) /. 
a -> 1/2, {x, 0, \[Pi] - eps}], t, t == Tan[x/2],Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1/10]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[Piecewise[ {{Inactive[Integrate][-8/(1 + t^2), {t, 0, Infinity}],  t >= 0 && eps + 2*Pi*C[1] <= 0}}, Inactive[Integrate][ (8*(-1 + 2*Cos[2*ArcTan[t]]))/((1 + t^2)*(-5 + 4*Cos[2*ArcTan[t]])),  {t, 0, Cot[eps/2]}]], Element[C[1], Integers] &&  t + Tan[Pi*C[1]] >= 0 &&  ((Inequality[0, Less, eps + 2*Pi*C[1], Less, Pi] &&  t <= Cot[eps/2 + Pi*C[1]]) || (C[1] > -1/2 && eps + 2*Pi*C[1] <= 0))]`

and a warning " Warning: contradictory assumption(s) Subscript[[ConstantC], 1][Element][DoubleStruckCapitalZ]&&
DSolve`IntegrateChangeVariablesDump`nIV$1749501>=-Tan[[Pi] Subscript[[ConstantC], 1]]&&
-(1/2)<Subscript[[ConstantC], 1]&&0<eps&&eps<1/10&&Subscript[[ConstantC], 1]<=-(eps/(2 [Pi])) encountered"

repeated twice. The result is incorrect in view of

```
Activate[int /. eps -> 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[Piecewise[{{-4*Pi, t >= 0 && 2*Pi*C[1] <= 0}},  Integrate[(8*(-1 + 2*Cos[2*ArcTan[t]]))/ ((1 + t^2)*(-5 + 4*Cos[2*ArcTan[t]])), {t, 0, ComplexInfinity}]],  Element[C[1], Integers] && t + Tan[Pi*C[1]] >= 0 &&  ((Inequality[0, Less, 2*Pi*C[1], Less, Pi] && t <= Cot[Pi*C[1]]) ||  (C[1] > -1/2 && 2*Pi*C[1] <= 0))]`

The command

```
Limit[Activate[int], eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

is running without any response for a few hours.

The question is: how to make this change correctly, obtaining the correct result `0`?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have to also specify `t>=0`:

```
int = IntegrateChangeVariables[
  Inactive[Integrate][(-2*Cos[x] + 2 a)/(1 - 2 a*Cos[x] + a^2) /. 
    a -> 1/2, {x, 0, \[Pi] - eps}], t, t == Tan[x/2], 
  Assumptions -> 1/10 > eps > 0 && t >= 0]
(*
Inactive[Integrate][(8 (-1 + 3 t^2))/(
 1 + 10 t^2 + 9 t^4), {t, 0, Cot[eps/2]}]
*)



Limit[Activate[int], eps -> 0]
(*0*)
```

I would think `IntegrateChangeVariables` should know the domain of `t`, since it has the transform function from `x` to `t`, and the integration bounds in `x`. But for some reason it had to be specified here.

My version:

```
$Version
(*"13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)"*)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in 13.3.1 on Windows 10. I obtain "$Assumptions::cas: Warning: contradictory assumption(s) Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]&&DSolve`IntegrateChangeVariablesDump`nIV$9003>=-Tan[\[Pi] Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]]&&-(1/2)<Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]&&0<eps&&eps<1/10&&Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]<=-(eps/(2 \[Pi])) encountered." and

Comment: `Piecewise[{{Inactive[Integrate][-8/(1 + t^2), {t, 0, Infinity}] + 
    Inactive[Integrate][(8*(-1 + 3*t^2))/(1 + 10*t^2 + 9*t^4), 
     {t, 0, Cot[eps/2]}], Element[C[1], Integers] && 
    t + Tan[Pi*C[1]] >= 0 && C[1] > -1/2 && eps + 2*Pi*C[1] <= 0}}, 
 Inactive[Integrate][(8*(-1 + 3*t^2))/(1 + 10*t^2 + 9*t^4),   {t, 0, Cot[eps/2]}]]` and then the unevaluated  limit.
Maybe, this is a session depending result.

Comment: I added my `$Version`, it might be because of that; I don't get any Messages when I run it.

Comment: +1. Thank you. However, I can't accept it since your code does not work on Linux in Wolfram Cloud too.

Comment: @user64494 That is fair